# Extract part of a link using php?

Tags: php, curl, extract

I am trying to grab the ID of my link from every single one and output it to a db which i will then use to go and scrape the actual page.

So i will grab the id, curl the page link then parse the details.

So far i have my links clickable, it's just trying to get the certain part of my links that is the hard part.

I have tried $_GET['id'] but this won't work as the id's are not in that format.

Here is the way my links are set out:

download.php/1000338/The%20Rise%20and%20Fall%20of%20Legs%20Diamond%20%5B1960%5D.avi.torrent

what i want to grab is the 1000338 part but i want it to do this for every single one and ofcourse they are not the same.

Any help is very much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: so something like this?


    <?php

$id = "download.php/";
var_dump( explode( '/', $id ) );

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$link="download.php/1000338/The%20Rise%20and%20Fall%20of%20Legs%20Diamond%20%5B1960%5D.avi.torrent";

$x=explode('/',$link);

$id=$x[1];
```

demo:http://codepad.viper-7.com/cWYXKe

using your code:

```
 $rss = simplexml_load_file('RSS FEED HERE'); 
echo '<h1>'. $rss->channel->title . '</h1>'; 
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) { 
//echo the link echo '<h2><a href="'. $item->link .'">' . $item->title . "</a></h2>"; 
//echo the date echo "<p>" . $item->pubDate . "</p>"; 
//echo the description echo "<p>" . $item->description . "</p>"
$x=explode('/',$item->link);
$id=$x[1];
}
```

then use $id any way you like

Comment: how would i make it so that it would grab from all links though, as every id is different each time a page is posted.

Comment: how are you scraping the page?

Comment: i am grabbing the RSS feed using

//RSS Read
$rss = simplexml_load_file('RSS FEED HERE');

echo '<h1>'. $rss->channel->title . '</h1>';

foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {

//echo the link
   echo '<h2><a href="'. $item->link .'">' . $item->title . "</a></h2>";
   //echo the date
   echo "<p>" . $item->pubDate . "</p>";
   //echo the description
   echo "<p>" . $item->description . "</p>";

sorry, not sure how to format this neatly

Comment: that's more of a new question, "how to extract all the links from an rss feed" but cant you just use `$item->link`

Comment: i am grabbing all links from RSS feed, i have the page doing that just now, i just need to grab the id's then i can parse that data and scrape those id's

Comment: well if you have the links, where's the problem, specifically? you can just use the above code inside your loop

Comment: i have the links outputting onto the index.php

what i need is to now automatically get the id's of those links, use the to scrape the page it links to and grab the html i choose from that page.

Pretty new to PHP, sorry if i am not making sense here.

Say i have a website, i wanted to scrape each page that was posted to the RSS and i wanted the "title", "description", "genre", "imdb link" etc

make more sense to you now ?

Comment: Brian, edited with my last word on this question. @php_nub_qq :P

Comment: i wouldent be so quick to jump to that conclusion myself. its easy to get lost in the code jungle

Comment: i have only just learned some parts of PHP still learning, i am not trying to troll anyone, got it working to give me the id now so will be able to do it from there, much easier.

thanks again and sorry if you think i was trolling but i genuinely am not.